# Problema con variable en python

Tags: python, tkinter, variables

estoy elaborando una aplicación en la cual tengo un botón que abre una nueva ventana (***código de abajo***) y en esa ventana hago una conexión con SQLite para poner los datos de esa BD en un combobox.

El código funciona bien pero tengo un problema con la última línea ya que me arroja un error "***NameError: name 'Combo_Marca' is not defined***"

Según yo ya lo tenía definido pero me dice que no es así, he usado ese mismo código en otros proyectos y no he tenido errores hasta ahora, que puede ser? agradezco su ayuda.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

def Nueva_Ventana():
    Ventana1 = Toplevel()
    Frame= Frame(Ventana1, bd=2, relief=SOLID, padx=10, pady=3)
            
    L1 = Label(Frame, text="Elija una marca: ").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=9)
    Combo_Marca = ttk.Combobox(Frame).grid(row=0, column=1, pady=9)   
        
    Frame.place(x=86, y=140)
    
def create_table():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('vehicles.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST autos ('models' TEXT, 'year' DATE);")
    conn.commit()

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO autos VALUES ('Ford Falcon', 1965);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO autos VALUES ('Chevy BelAir', 1954);")
    conn.commit()

    cur.close()
    conn.close()


def combo_values_input():
    
    conn = sqlite3.connect('vehicles.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    
    query = cur.execute('SELECT models FROM autos')
    
    data = []
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        data.append(row[0])
    return data
    
    cur.close()
    conn.close()


Combo_Marca ['values'] = combo_values_input()     #<-------aquí el problema
```

Comment: Esa variable solo existe en el ámbito de la función

Comment: Como lo puedo solucionar? no encuentro la forma

Comment: 1) declaras la variable como global. 2) retornas ese valor

Answer (score 2):

En el ejemplo que muestras solo hay una variable local llamada Combo_Marca en la función `Nueva Ventana`. Aunque en realidad vale None porque al mismo tiempo que la declaras utilizas grid, que retorna `None`. Tendrías que retornar `Combo_Marca` y guardar el valor en una variable. Aparte de eso tu código tiene varios problemas, por ejemplo utilizas la palabra `Frame` con mayúsculas que esta reservada por tkinter.

Aqui una versión funcional

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

def Nueva_Ventana():
    Ventana1 = Toplevel()
    frame= Frame(Ventana1, bd=2, relief=SOLID, padx=10, pady=3)
        
    L1 = Label(frame, text="Elija una marca: ").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=9)
    Combo_Marca = ttk.Combobox(frame)
    Combo_Marca.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=9)
    frame.place(x=86, y=140)
    return Combo_Marca
    
def create_table():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('vehicles.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST autos ('models' TEXT, 'year' DATE);")
    conn.commit()

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO autos VALUES ('Ford Falcon', 1965);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO autos VALUES ('Chevy BelAir', 1954);")
    conn.commit()

    cur.close()
    conn.close()


def combo_values_input():
    
    conn = sqlite3.connect('vehicles.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    
    query = cur.execute('SELECT models FROM autos')
    
    data = []
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        data.append(row[0])
    return data
    
    cur.close()
    conn.close()


Combo_Marca = Nueva_Ventana()
Combo_Marca['values'] = combo_values_input()
```

Las dos ventanas se crean porque cuando llamas a `TopLevel()` estás creando una ventana secundaria, no principal. Esta ventana es un widget de tkinter, y todos los widgets deben recibir un padre, si no se les indica uno automáticamente llaman a `Tk()`. Por eso se crea otra ventana, la principal.

Podrías agregar esto al inicio de tu código:

```
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
```

Y pasarlo como parametro a `TopLevel(root)`

Comment: Hola, Eh estado probando el código pero al momento de correrlo, en automático se abren 2 ventanas, una en blanco y la otra donde está el combobox. He estado moviendo y el problema parece estar en las 2 últimas líneas de "Combo_Marca". Aún no le doy

Comment: Respuesta editada!

Comment: Lo entiendo mejor ahora, muchas gracias!